# mysql left join syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, left-join

Really stumped on this one. It should be a simple left join to a second table but i'm getting a syntax error.  Trying to get the last due date on incomplete items.

**Code:**

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM TBLTICKETHEADER h, 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT HEADERID, MAX(DUEDATE)
                       FROM TBLTICKETITEM
                       WHERE YEAR(COMPLETEDDATE) = 9999
                       GROUP BY HEADERID) ld ON ld.HEADERID = h.HEADERID
```

**ERROR:**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT HEADERID, MAX(DUEDATE)
>                          FROM TBLTICKETIT' at line 3

Comment: remove the comma before left join

Comment: `FROM TBLTICKETHEADER h, ` remove the , next to `h`

Answer (score 3):

You have a comma after your h on the from clause. Remove it and your query should run.

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM TBLTICKETHEADER h
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT HEADERID, MAX(DUEDATE)
                       FROM TBLTICKETITEM
                       WHERE YEAR(COMPLETEDDATE) = 9999
                       GROUP BY HEADERID) AS ld ON ld.HEADERID = h.HEADERID
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  That's just embarrassing when you stare at something for an hour and don't see that!  I must have needed more coffee this morning.